# How do I get the whole matrix in VBA from a pointer returned by a C++ DLL?

Tags: c++, arrays, vba, matrix, dll

I have written a piece of code in C++ for a DLL that gets from VBA an array as  input, and creates a new one, which in turn is given back to VBA.

The DLL .h is written as follows:

```
// FieldTrans.h
#ifdef FIELDTRANS_EXPORTS
#define FIELDTRANS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FIELDTRANS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
    // Returns the normalized cardinal sinus coefficient
    FIELDTRANS_API double _stdcall SinC(double x);
    // Returns the interpolated field matrix: 180° x 360° with Res step
    FIELDTRANS_API double _stdcall ShannonInterp(double** Matrix[], int MatrixHeight, int MatrixWidth, double Res, double DeltaTheta, double DeltaPhi);
};
```

And the .cpp file:

```
// FieldTrans.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FieldTrans.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

double _stdcall SinC(double x)
{
    double y;
    y = 1;
    if (x != 0)
    {
        y = sin(3.14159265358979323846 * x) / (3.14159265358979323846 * x);
    }
    return y;
}

double** _stdcall ShannonInterp(double** Matrix, int MatrixHeight, int MatrixWidth, double Res, double DeltaTheta, double DeltaPhi)
{
    int k, l, m, n;
    double iRes, jRes;
    double ThetaSinC, PhiSinC;
    int Height = static_cast<int> (180 / Res);
    int Width = static_cast<int> (360 / Res);
    double** Interpolated = new double*[Height];
    k = 0;
    m = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    {
        Interpolated[i] = new double[Width];
        iRes = i * Res;
        do
        {
            k = k + 1;
            m = k + 1;
        } while (iRes >(k + 1) * DeltaTheta);
        if (m > MatrixHeight)
        {
            m = MatrixHeight - 1;
        }
        ThetaSinC = SinC((iRes - k * DeltaTheta) / DeltaTheta);
        l = 0;
        n = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
        {
            jRes = j * Res;
            do
            {
                l = l + 1;
                n = l + 1;
            } while (jRes >(l + 1) * DeltaPhi);
            if (n > MatrixWidth)
            {
                n = 0;
            }
            PhiSinC = SinC((jRes - l * DeltaPhi) / DeltaPhi);
            Interpolated[i][j] = 1 * ThetaSinC * PhiSinC + 2 * ThetaSinC * (1 - PhiSinC) + 3 * (1 - ThetaSinC) * PhiSinC + 4 * (1 - ThetaSinC) * (1 - PhiSinC);
        }
    }
    return Interpolated;
}
```

After having defined the calling names in a .def file, I've written on my VBA code the following declaration to call one of the functions:

```
Private Declare Function ShannonInterp Lib "C:\NSI2000\Script\FieldTrans.dll" (ByRef Matrix() As Double, ByVal MatrixHeight As Integer, ByVal MatrixWidth As Integer, ByVal Res As Double, ByVal DeltaTheta As Double, ByVal DeltaPhi As Double) As Double
```

And I can use the function like this without any crashes or error:

```
PointerCo = ShannonInterp(AmplCo, PointsTheta, PointsPhi, Resolution, 181 / (PointsTheta+1), 361 / (PointsPhi+1))
```

My question is: I'm guessing `PointerCo` is a pointer, but I need to store in a variable the whole matrix it refers to. Is it possible? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't "interop" between VBA and C++ like that.

By far the easiest way to do this is to use the SAFEARRAY type of VT_VARIANT on the C++ side, which maps to a classical `Variant` array type in VBA. There are lots of tutorials on this scattered across the internet.

If you haven't used Microsoft COM before, and its related supporting classes, I'd recommend your setting aside a good month to get up to speed.

Comment: would you mind pointing me to a tutorial "for dummies" that can fit my case?